# Getting error when installing package "cufflinks" in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, package

Getting error when installing the package "cufflinks" in pycharm. see below screenshot [image: screenshot]

Comment: Clear picture, but you could also copy paste the error message to your question.

Comment: @Tushar Modi on my pycharm all is instaled ok. Try install first plotly and pandas. If not then install by pip from env terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new virtual environment then working fine and also run the cufflinks package.
pip install cufflinks